# How to interpolate vertices when clipping?

Tags: interpolation, rasterizer, clipping

When we clip in homogeneous clip space, we have to generate a new vertex located at the intersection between the edge and the clip plane. We thus have to interpolate the $(x , y, z , w)$ position of both vertices to generate the new vertex position. It seems all well and good, but what should I do when the generated vertex after interpolation has a w of 0?

It doesn’t work because the w-divide makes the point go to infinity (division by zero).

So should I ensure that I never generate vertices with a w of 0 (how?)? Or should I just deal with the null w (how?)?

You might say that this situation never happen, but it actually does happen, especially when the z of the vertices are set to their w, for skyboxes for example. In this case, when we clip against the near plane (z = 0 in clip space) and interpolate the position, we will end up with a z of 0 but also a w of 0...

Comment: "*it actually does happen, especially when the z of the vertices are set to their w, for skyboxes for example.*" That changes nothing about the math here. The whole point of (near) clipping is to ensure that all vertices have a positive value for `w`. If you get a value of `w` for a near-clipped vertex, then you did your clipping computation wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Points in front of the camera have $w > 0$ strictly, by definition. I would say that if clipping is giving you points with $w = 0$ then something is going wrong.

Consider the left/right/top/bottom clip planes. There is no way that a triangle can span from part of the visible frustum, to the $w = 0$ camera plane or behind it, without also crossing outside one of the frustum side planes—or else the near plane, which lies at some positive distance $w_\text{near} > 0$.

You mentioned skyboxes and setting $z = w$ in the vertex shader output. Such geometry must cross the frustum side planes before it can get to the near plane. (How could part of a skybox get close enough to the camera to be clipped by the near plane only?) If you are correctly clipping it against *all* of the frustum planes, you must end up with $w > 0$ in the final vertex.